# Is it possible to change the raster image size on the fly?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to change the raster image size on the fly. I have 10 band therefore I cannot use OpenCV. `gdal.Warp()` gives the option to change the size but I have to save it in a folder. Is there something that allows me to change the size and hold the image in a variable, in Jupyter notebook especially.

```
 gdal.Warp(opu,fn,dstSRS = "EPSG: 32614",width = 3400,height = 3400)
```

I want something like this

```
input_image=cv2.resize( input_image,(3200,3200))
```

Comment: Maybe you could use https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/mem.html or https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/memory.html.

Comment: I'd highly recommend rasterio instead of using gdal directly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you noticed `gdal.Warp` needs an "output". To avoid unnecessary I/O operations, you could save a temporary VRT like that :

```py
gdal.Warp('temp.vrt', fn, dstSRS="EPSG: 32614", width=3400, height=3400)
```

And then after loading this VRT into Python, you can do whatever you want with it, for example :

```py
ds = gdal.Open('temp.vrt')
array = ds.ReadAsArray()
print(array.shape)  # (10, 3400, 3400)
```